# When is the deal Mono.fromCallback ? (reactive)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I still do not understand when to apply this method. In fact, it is similar to Mono.just, but I heard that callback is used for heavy operations if it needs to be performed separately from other flows. Now I use it like this, but is it correct.

Here is an example of use, I wrap sending a firebase notification in a callback since the operation is long

```
 @Override
    public Mono<NotificationDto> sendMessageAllDevice(NotificationDto notification) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> fcmProvider.sendPublicMessage(notification))
                .thenReturn(notification);
    }
```

maybe I still had to wrap up here in Mono.just ?

Comment: Did you mean `fromCallable` in your title (as you use that in your code)? If so, this is to integrate between two different types of asynchronous APIs. As an aside, you tagged rx-java, but Mono is Project Reactor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which thread you want `fcmProvider.sendPublicMessage(...)` to be run on.

Either the one currently executing `sendMessageAllDevice(...)`:

```java
T result = fcmProvider.sendPublicMessage(notification);
return Mono.just(result);
```

Or the one(s) the underlying mono relies on:

```java
Callable<T> callable = () -> fcmProvider.sendPublicMessage(notification);
return Mono.fromCallable(callable);
```

I would guess you need the latter approach.

Comment: In the latter approach, there is no difference with what I have now.

Comment: @Volatail yes, exactly. I just used an intermediate variable to make it more obvious when `fcmProvider.sendPublicMessage(notification)` is effectively called.

Comment: I wrap the request coming to the server in Mono.just, inside I already call Mono.fromCallback. As you say, callback is executed underlying mono, so is it still correct to send the execution of a heavy operation there, maybe Mono.just will be more appropriate here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mono.just(computeX()), computeX() is called immediately. No want you want(I guess).

If you use Mono.fromCallable(() -> computeX()), the computation is still not performed. I mean computeX() is only called when you subscribe to it. Maybe using .map, .flatMap, etc.

**Important**: if computeX() return Mono you doe not need to use Mono.fromCallable. It's only for blocking code

Answer (score -1):

As you explained in the description, `Mono.fromCallable` is used when you want to compute a result with an async execution (mostly some heavy operation).

Since, you have already generated the `Mono` with `Mono.fromCallable` you do not have to wrap it again with `Mono.just`.